# Travelling to two different Schengen countries for more than 90 days with a 10-day gap

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas, denmark

I am a student and I have planned academic trips on the following dates in the following countries:

- 11 August 2018 to 20 August 2018 in Dresden, Germany. (9 days)
- 1 September 2018 to 28 November 2018 in Copenhagen, Denmark. (88 days)

I want to know if I should apply for two different Schengen visas or I for one long-term visa, which will cover both trips.

In the latter case, when I am applying for a long-term visa, Hlhow do I justify support and explain I will be coming back. And which embassy to apply to?

EDIT1: Looking at the visa constraints, I have shifted my second visit to the end of the first visit so that I enter Europe once.

Now I am wondering if I should reduce my second visit to 80 days, so that I will have to take only one Schengen visa for 90 days and I will stay in Germany for 10 days and in Copenhagen for the next 80 days.

Is there any other way to get a 100-day visa for Europe?

Comment: Have you been invited to make these trips? What ties can you prove to your home country?

Comment: It is likely not possible for you to get visas for those travel plans. You are staying too long in total to use short-term (type C) visas, so you would need a national long-term (type D) visa. On the other hand, each of your stays are too short for a long-term visa. so that likely neither Germany nor Denmark will feel competent or required to issue a long-term visa.

Comment: It should be possible to plan the Denmark visit with a few extra days to overcome jet lag, so it is long enough to apply for a Danish D visa and a German C visa.

Comment: @o.m. Maybe, maybe not. National long-term visas are not issued for arbitrary leisure or tourism, but for a specific purpose. If the purpose is some kind of academic activity for a period of less than 90 days, I doubt that it will hold. It is of course possible to try.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, the academic stay has 88 days minimum duration. Adding two days for arrival/departure chores at each end sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @Traveller Yes. I plan to attend a summer school and then go for a Thesis Project.

Answer (score 3):

Since your stay will involve visiting the Schengen area for more than 90 days in a 180 day period, you will need to apply for a long term (D type) visa from one of the countries you're visiting.

Whether or not you're eligible for one depends on the exact purpose of your visit and the documentation you have, so we can't help you out without seeing those.